# Member variable access with pointer-to-function

Tags: c++

Is there a way for the function pointed to by a class member function pointer to access the member variables of the function pointer class?   Or do I have to pass the member variable to the function?

```
class A {
public:

    int var;
    void(*fooPtr) (void);

    //ctor
    A(void(*funcPtr)(void)) :fooPtr(funcPtr){}
};

void foo(void) {
    int test = var;
}

A classInstance(&foo);
```

compiler error: 'var' was not declared in this scope

Comment: You'll need explicitly pass this or *this to foo.

Comment: I recommend that you space your code before pasting it next time. It is hard to answer otherwise.

Comment: `foo()` actually isn't a member of your class!

Comment: You have to pass some information to the freestanding function (either the entire class object or a member).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foo() is not a member of the A class. You just pass a pointer to the function to the constructor. You have to pass the pointer or reference to the class instance to the foo() function so it can access the `var` instance.

```
class A {
public:
    int var;
    void(*fooPtr) (const A&);

    //ctor
    A(void(*funcPtr)(const A&)) :fooPtr(funcPtr){}
};

void foo(const A &a) {
    int test = a.var;
}

A classInstance(&foo);
```

It's even better to use typeddefs to avoid this verbose function pointer construct.

```
class A {
typedef void(*MyPtr)(const A&);

public:
    int var;
    MyPtr fooPtr;

    A(MyPtr fooPtr) :fooPtr(fooPtr){}
};

void foo(const A &a) {
    int test = a.var;
}

A classInstance(&foo);
```